# How to store ModelChoicieField value?

Tags: python, django

I'm new with Django and I have a little problem : I have a DB (**MyClass**) with several attributes and I would like to print on a web page only those who have their **category** attributes equal to one of the elements of the DB **Categories**. For this, I want to use a ModelChoiceField which will display all the possibilities from the **Categories** DB. Then, I think that I have to store the one chosen by the user in order to display in the webpage the corresponding element of the **MyClass** DB. I tried the following code :

**views.py**

```
def my_view(request):

  test = False 
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MyForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cat = form.save(commit = False)
        test = True
        my_var = MyClass.objects.filter(category = cat.category)
  else:
    form = MyForm()
    var = MyClass.objects.all()

  return render(request, '/path/to/template.html', {'form': form, 'my_var': my_var, 'test': test})
```

**forms.py**

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Categories.objects.all().order_by('name'))
```

**page.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% if test %}
      <p>
      {% for element in my_var %}
            <td>{{ element.title }}</td><br>
      {% endfor %}
      </p>
{% else %}
<strong>Select the category : </strong><br>
    <form id="form" action="{% url 'page' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Find" />
    </form>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

But it doesn't seem to work ... the problem is that it seems to never fills the condition `request.method == 'POST'` ... After hours of research, I didn't manage to find an answer : does someone know how to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `method="post"` into the form tag in your template.

(Note, you don't need the enctype attribute there - that's only necessary when you have a file field.)

Comment: Aw yes, I didn't managed to see that ... it solved the problem, thanks !